# Multiple images in scilab simultaneously

Tags: scilab

How do we display more than one image simultaneously in scilab? I used to do it using figure,imshow() in matlab. Whats the scilab alternative?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Multiple imshow windows

Assuming you are using SIVP for image processing in SciLab, it is currently only possible to show one *imshow* window at a time.

Quote from the  [SIVP imshow documentation](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/func-list-0.4.1/imshow.htm) :

> **Bugs and Shortcomings**
>
> Only one imshow window can pop up.

### Workaround

A workaround is to combine multiple images and show that image, for example:

```
// Two example images
im1 = ones(400,600);
im2 = rand(400,600);

// Put images side by side
im3 = [im1 im2];
imshow(im3);

// or put them top-to-bottom
im3 = [im1 ; im2 ];
imshow(im3);
```

When combining images be sure to have matching dimensions, so when placing images side-by-side the number of rows must match and when placing them top-to-bottom the number of columns must match.

Comment: Yes, I am using SIVP. Will using SIP or IPD enhance the image processing experience in Scilab as compared to SIVP? What are the differences?

Comment: For my image processing projects I use a combination of C++ and  OpenCV 2.X. So I don't think I'm the right person to judge the different toolboxes, but [SIP](http://siptoolbox.sourceforge.net/) provides a comparison of the three. It seems that SIP has a broader [set of functions](http://siptoolbox.sourceforge.net/doc/sip-0.7.0-reference/index.html) and doesn't seem to have the single imshow shortcoming( [imshow in SIP](http://siptoolbox.sourceforge.net/doc/sip-0.7.0-reference/imshow.html) )